# UIButton not working or gets unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uibutton

I have an odd (at least to me) issue in that I used the pod Localize_Swift to localize my app.

I have two issues that I cannot figure out as nearly all documentation about localizing only covers text on the same vc as the localize menu or button.  In my case, I have localize strings set up and across the entire app, they are in use with a .localize suffix.

First issue:
The button either does not work.  The print() function never gets triggered or if it does work, appears to be randomly, I get the unrecognized selector sent to instance that lists the func changeLanguage as the cause.  I commented out all of the code within the function, but still received the error.
I have also deleted the func and recreated it, but still no go.

Second issue: 
How to initialize the localization across the entire app with the strings?

SettingsViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Localize_Swift


class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController
{

    var availableLanguages = Localize.availableLanguages()
    var actionSheet: UIAlertController!

    @IBOutlet weak var switchlangButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var flagImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back".localized, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(SettingsViewController.backBtnAction(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

        configureView()
        availableLanguages.removeAtIndex(0)
        print(availableLanguages)

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SettingsViewController.setTranslatedText), name: LCLLanguageChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }


    func setTranslatedText(){
        switchlangButton.setTitle("Switch Language".localized(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        flagImageView.image = UIImage(named: "flag-en".localized() + ".png")



    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBAction func changeLanguage(sender: AnyObject) {
        print ("changeLanguageButton pressed")
        actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Switch Language".localized(), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        for language in availableLanguages {
            let displayName = Localize.displayNameForLanguage(language)
            let languageAction = UIAlertAction(title: displayName, style: .Default, handler: {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                Localize.setCurrentLanguage(language)
            })
            actionSheet.addAction(languageAction)
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localized(), style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        })
        actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configureView(){
        switchlangButton.setTitle("Switch Language".localized(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        flagImageView.image = UIImage(named: "flag-en".localized() + ".png")


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {


        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func backBtnAction(sender:UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }



}
```

Screenshot of the Settings scene

[image: Screenshot of the Settings scene]

Just an FYI for troubleshooting, the image does not work either.

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting please ?

Comment: It seems that i cannot recreate it.  The button simply does not work.  Do you see any issues that would prevent it from working?  I have deleted and recreated a new IB Scene, I have deleted and recreated the button and function

Comment: Could you put a break point in the method changeLanguage and check whether control is going there ? Also put a breakpoint in the viewDidLoad() method and print the switchlangButton button object using the command po switchlangButton in the console. When you print switchlangButton, check what is the selector associated with the switchlangButton.

Comment: I am at the ViewDidLoad now, but do not understand the "command po" comment

Comment: Is this what you mean?  (lldb) po
Enter expressions, then terminate with an empty line to evaluate:
1 switchlangButton
2 
<UIButton: 0x7f9e51437d50; frame = (0 0; 1000 1000); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000231f20>>

Comment: When control comes to your breakpoint in the viewDidLoad, open the console and type in po switchlangButton. It will print the switchlangButton object also there will be something called selector there can you pls check what does that selector contains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122028/discussion-between-iamyogish-and-david-sanford).